# How to use StreamWriter.WriteAsync and catch exceptions?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, try-catch, .net-4.5, streamwriter

I have simple function to write files.

```
public static void WriteFile(string filename, string text)
{
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filename);
    try
    {
        file.Write(text);
    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have no write permission in that folder.");
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }

    file.Close();
}
```

How can I convert my code to use `StreamWriter.WriteAsync` with try-catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async public static void WriteFile(string filename, string text)
{
    StreamWriter file = null;
    try
    {
        file = new StreamWriter(filename);
        await file.WriteAsync(text);
    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have no write permission in that folder.");
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (file != null) file.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. VS says: `The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.`

Comment: Aaah there is `async` before method name. I didn't saw this. Now it compiles, but when I try to write in windows directory for example - there is no MessageBox with error.

Comment: I have "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" instead of MessageBox with "You have no write permission in that folder.".

Comment: @Kamil please show your *real* code. I see the messagebox when I run above code.

Comment: This is real code. I just translated text in message box to english. I will add code that calls that method.

Comment: Well, I messed up. I had StreamWriter constructor outside try-catch. Now it works. Thanks.